# How to disable sku from dashboard ? Magento 2

Tags: magento2, sku, dashboard

I need to disable Sku from the dashboard and not from the code, is this possible?
[image]

Comment: in product edit page you want to disable sku text field ???

Comment: sorry, a mistake from my side. needed disable sku from dashboard

Comment: dashboard means ?

Comment: i mean admin panel

Comment: admin panel means edit product page ??

Comment: Rk Rathod, thanks for your attention. I need to hide the sku attribute from the admin panel so that the admin panel that is not displayed on the product pages and the page for viewing the frontend  of the product.

Comment: simply you want to hide sku on frontend right ????

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104598/discussion-between-robinio-and-rk-rathod).

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, by default there is no way to disable SKU in the admin panel.
2. Second, if you think that disabling sku from backend will make it disabled in the frontend thats not possible without modifying the code. Just make modifications in the code.
3. Log into your server or navigate in your localhost directory.
4. Locate the following file: **`/your_magento_root_directory/app/design/frontend/Vendor/VendorTheme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/attribute.phtml`**
5. If you don't have a custom theme then make modifications in the vendor and check.
6. Override in vendor line 31: **`/your_magento_root_directory/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/attribute.phtml`**

Replace the original code

```
if ($_attributeLabel && $_attributeLabel == 'default') {
    $_attributeLabel = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_code)->getStoreLabel();
}
```

With the following:

```
if ($_attributeLabel && $_attributeLabel == 'default') {
    $_attributeLabel = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_code)->getStoreLabel();
    if ($_attributeLabel=='SKU') {
        $_attributeLabel='';
    }
}
```

7. After this run php bin/magento cache:flush or from admin panel.
8. Confirm that its working or not.
9. If you want to override this in app then just make a file in your custom theme i.e. **`/magento_root_directory/app/design/frontend/Vendor/VendorTheme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/attribute.phtml`**